# odbc_result_all formatting

Tags: odbc

$selectVolID = "Select COUNT(VolunteerID) from planetVolunteers";
$getVolID = odbc_exec($connect, $selectVolID);

echo odbc_result_all($getVolID);

gives:

Expr1000
49
1

49 is the correct count. I want to change the Expr1000 to something legible and get rid of that 1 (which i assume means there are no more values to count).

Comment: any more ideas on the extra number?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias in the SELECT statement to a more descriptive name:

```
SELECT COUNT(VoluneerID) NumVolunteers from ...
```

Depending on the underlying database engine, it is possible that the `AS` keyword migh be needed in front of the alias.

I have dealt very little with PHP, so I do not know about the 1 that is printed.

Comment: This fixes the the table name issue but not the issue with the 1 after the table. I've done tons of research and can't find any solution. Any ideas?

Comment: The number is actually the number of cells. Is there a way to trim that number off? I only need the COUNT value.

Answer (score 0):

The number at the end should be the total number of rows returned. The best way I know of to remove it would be to put it in a hidden input, which means you can refer to it later with javascript or something if you really needed to, and also lets you hide it easily.. anything wrapped around the odbc_results_all function only effects the returning row count instead of the whole table (so you can use anything, maybe a div will be better).

```
echo "<input value=\"" . odbc_result_all($getVolID) . "\" type=\"text\" style=\"display:none;\">";
```